# Return Elasticsearch highlight results in position order?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, highlight

I'm currently using the [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#boundary-characters) feature that elasticsearch offers in my query. However, the one thing I'm not quite clear on is about how the results are ordered. I would prefer they come back in the `order that they appear` in a paragraph instead of importance/score. This is so I can concatenate them with `...`'s in the same order as they are in the original document (similar to Google results). However, they are currently returning in some weighted order based on best match?

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to do additional post processing on the field after seeing the highlight results.

I see there is a `"order" : "score"` option for a highlight, but there doesn't seem to be any other documented options to change the return order. (And as an aside, I don't understand the difference between the default order and the scoring order).

Here's a snippet of the highlight portion of my query.

```
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "synopsis": {
        "fragment_size": 150,
        "number_of_fragments": 4
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing a bit of playing around, I discovered that the `fast-vector-highlighter` will natively sort the fragments in order of appearance in the original document. To enable this, I needed to add `"term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"` to my synopsis field mapping.

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "synopsis" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
    }
  }
}
```

and then use my highlight query as so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "synopsis": "foo"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "synopsis": {
        "type": "fvh",
        "fragment_size": 150,
        "number_of_fragments": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: Using `"order" : "score"` would cause the ordering to follow the the scoring schema, which does not necessarily follow start position offset order. I believe the exact code for this comparator can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-highlighter/5.2.0/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder.java#ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder.getWeightedFragInfoList%28java.util.List%29), which seems to base it on the fragment's boost and then its startoffset.

Comment: Does it works with spean near therms? Because i'm getting missing `highlighting` for several results in my query.